# Rendering as a function of DOM state

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

Imagine a react component that renders an absolutely positioned element. This element's position on the page is a function of data extracted from the DOM (not from any component state).

**Does react have a good pattern for rendering as a function of DOM state?**

---

My best idea I'd call **double rendering:**

1. Read the DOM in the relevant `componentDidMount`/`componentDidUpdate`.
2. `setState` of the dependent component or otherwise re-`render` it.
3. Requires defining `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent infinite `render`/`componentDidMount` loops.

Comment: Good question. I would imagine something along the lines of listing to `DOMTreeModified` to detect changes and then do as you wish.

Comment: What I'm concerned about is the correct React approach. I'm currently triggering two renders for every normal render. The actual job of analysing the DOM is something I'm ok with and which would be a separate question.

Comment: 1) To clarify, by DOM you mean some arbitrary part of the page not part of your specific React component (this is what I'm currently assuming), and 2) you could set the `DOMTreeModified` listener in `componentDidMount` and when the event is called, trigger a state change. A state change will in turn trigger a re-render.

Comment: (1) In my concrete case I'm calculating the width of text owned by a component in order to place a visual cursor at the end of that text. (2) The method I use to determine when things change is incidental, what I'm worried about is causing a second render. It may not seem like a lot but it's multiplying the total amount of virtual renders by two. Or is it nothing to worry about?

Comment: The DOM is slow. That's what React is for. Don't feel guilty triggering renders. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The **componentDidMount** event is where you would want to do this.

> **componentDidMount - from the react docs**
>
> At this point in the lifecycle, the component has a DOM representation
> which you can access via React.findDOMNode(this).
>
> If you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks, set timers
> using setTimeout or setInterval, or send AJAX requests, perform those
> operations in this method.

I would place the absolute element on the page but out of view, and then move it into position in the **componentDidMount** event.

I wouldn't call this double rendering.

Comment: And as a pattern it's ok to split the rendering logic between `render` and `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Yeah I added another line from the docs to clarify that they(react team) intend for operations like this to happen during compnentDidMount

Comment: Yer this looks like the best approach. I was imagining I needed to channel everything back into `render` after `componentDidMount` (hence *double rendering*) but this seems cleaner.

Comment: There may be an issue with this. On the next render call, the element will be rendered out of view and then moved back into position. This will happen every time. `render` **does** need to be included in the logic.

Comment: You can also use the componentDidMount to add something to the dom. One big advantage of react is the virtual DOM. React will intelligently add the one new item instead of re-rendering the entire page.

Comment: But regardless we'll see react `render` and flush to DOM (placing the element out of view) then hit `componentDidUpdate` and move the element into the correct position. The next flush to DOM is the result of the same original `render` logic, thus the element is moved off screen again. Thus we have a flickering back and forth.

Comment: I meant to say that I agree this may be an issue, but I would still update from componentDidMount. Adding the element to the dom at this point is perfectly legit. Sorry if it seemed like i was debating your point.  =]